# Combining elements for filtering with Isotope

Tags: jquery, select, click, jquery-isotope

I'm currently using Isotope to filter a list of publications, but would like to be able to combine the standard, documented link-filter method with a select element, as my second list of filters is quite long.

The bit I'm struggling with is dealing with two distinct types of element and *combining* selected values into *one option array*. I can make the filters work independently of each other (code below) but they need to work together. How can I combine the two different actions (click or change) and two attributes (class= or value=) into one options array to pass to the isotop filter?

```
    var $container = $('#library');
// select ccskills publications by default
$container.isotope({ filter: '.ccskills' });

var $optionSets = $('#library-options .option-set'),
$optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

$optionLinks.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected
    if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
    return false;
    }
    var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
    $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');

    // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
    var options = {},
    key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
    value = $this.attr('data-option-value');

    // parse 'false' as false boolean
    value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
    options[ key ] = value;
    $container.isotope( options );
    return false;
});

    // using the 'chozen' plugin to style my select element
$(".chzn-select").chosen().change(
    function() {
        var industry = $("option:selected", this).val();
        $container.isotope({filter: industry});
    }
);
```

Comment: you can't possibly do that,because a user can't make both actions at the same time. otherwise use a global variable to collect the data and use an array merge[r] or something like that

Comment: Thanks Val. I want to combine the filters as two separate actions - I just need to make sure that this combination of filters is executed together. Otherwise I end up with what I currently have, which is the last action overriding the previous one! I'll have a look the merge you suggest.

Comment: I think I've figured it out (somewhat inelegantly!) - I'm checking the 'other' list from each feature and appending the filter to the one that I'm updating. Like so: ` $("#industry-dropdown").chosen().change(
  function() {
   var industry = $("option:selected", this).val();
   var publisher = $optionSets.find('a.selected').attr('data-option-value');
   $container.isotope({filter: industry+publisher});
  }
 );`

Comment: Sorry, can't seem to format my comment nicely

Comment: use the tick button usually on top of the tab button on keyboard its similar to single quote mark

Comment: Combining them into one array can only done with a multi-dimensional array otherwise they're just going to overwrite each other as you've experienced. I'm not sure about what Val is talking about with an array merge? That sounds like php. In javascript the method is called splice(). See: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Answer (score 17):

You need a multi-dimensional array, with an array dimension for each filter type you have. I've done that before and there's a live demo example [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170926022727/http://everyonelovessharing.com/misc/isotopedemo/)!

See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310073510/http://everyonelovessharing.com/misc/isotope.combofilter.js)! for the js.

**EDIT (Feb, 2020): Links to demo and JavaScript have been updated for 2020 with wayback machine urls**

In my js file you'll be interested in the end function called getComboFilters( filters )

```
function getComboFilter( filters ) {
    var i = 0;
    var comboFilters = [];
    var message = [];
    for ( var prop in filters ) {
        message.push( filters[ prop ].join(' ') );
        var filterGroup = filters[ prop ];
        // skip to next filter group if it doesn't have any values
        if ( !filterGroup.length ) {
            continue;
        }
        if ( i === 0 ) {
            // copy to new array
            comboFilters = filterGroup.slice(0);
        }
        else {
            var filterSelectors = [];
            // copy to fresh array
            var groupCombo = comboFilters.slice(0); // [ A, B ]
            // merge filter Groups
            for (var k=0, len3 = filterGroup.length; k < len3; k++) {
                for (var j=0, len2 = groupCombo.length; j < len2; j++) {
                    filterSelectors.push( groupCombo[j] + filterGroup[k] ); // [ 1, 2 ]
                }
            }
            // apply filter selectors to combo filters for next group
            comboFilters = filterSelectors;
        }
        i++;
    }
    comboFilters.sort();
    var comboFilter = comboFilters.join(', ');
    return comboFilter;
}
```

This function handles all of the pushing, splicing and sorting of the various sets of filter arrays but to use it you need to add it to your filter routine... well I say routine but it routines really because you seem to call the filter method 2 separate times:

```
$container.isotope({ filter: '.ccskills' });
```

and later:

```
 $container.isotope({filter: .industry});
```

If your going to filter types together all of your filter types are going to have to know about each other, meaning they're going to have to be inside the same javascript enclosure and the filter method needs to be called only once at which time it gets tested against all your filter type conditions.

using the getComboFilter( filters ) function you call the combination filter method like this:

```
var $container = $('#library');
var filters = {};
var comboFilter = getComboFilter( filters );
$container.isotope({ filter: comboFilter });
```

Finally, the full integration into your file would be somethign like this:

```
var $container = $('#library');
var filters = {};
var comboFilter = getComboFilter( filters );
$container.isotope({ filter: comboFilter });

// This next part targets all the possible filter items
// i.e. '.option-set a' just like your example

$('.option-set a').click(function(){
        // exit directly if filter already disabled
        if ($(this).hasClass('disabled') ){
            return false;
        }
        var $this = $(this);
        var $optionSet = $(this).parents('.option-set');
        var group = $optionSet.attr('data-filter-group');
        // store filter value in object
        var filterGroup = filters[ group ];
        if ( !filterGroup ) {
            filterGroup = filters[ group ] = [];
        }
        var comboFilter = getComboFilter( filters );
        $container.isotope({ filter: comboFilter });
});
function getComboFilter( filters ) {
    var i = 0;
    var comboFilters = [];
    var message = [];
    for ( var prop in filters ) {
        message.push( filters[ prop ].join(' ') );
        var filterGroup = filters[ prop ];
        // skip to next filter group if it doesn't have any values
        if ( !filterGroup.length ) {
            continue;
        }
        if ( i === 0 ) {
            // copy to new array
            comboFilters = filterGroup.slice(0);
        }
        else {
            var filterSelectors = [];
            // copy to fresh array
            var groupCombo = comboFilters.slice(0); // [ A, B ]
            // merge filter Groups
            for (var k=0, len3 = filterGroup.length; k < len3; k++) {
                for (var j=0, len2 = groupCombo.length; j < len2; j++) {
                    filterSelectors.push( groupCombo[j] + filterGroup[k] ); // [ 1, 2 ]
                }
            }
            // apply filter selectors to combo filters for next group
            comboFilters = filterSelectors;
        }
        i++;
    }
    comboFilters.sort();
    var comboFilter = comboFilters.join(', ');
    return comboFilter;
}
```

Hope this helps somebody! The demo is pretty slick.

Comment: Hi Drew, I think your demo is great, I'm having trouble adapting it to my needs, I have a checkbox selected instead of buttons, multichecks, no categories. I want to have the filterdisplay text to have clickable divs much like you have in your demo. Where when you click the display text of the filter selection, it would uncheck the checkbox and remove the filter. Here is my stackoverflow question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943895/isotope-combination-filter-display-i-want-to-split-the-text-array-into-divs

Hoping you could help as you're the closest solution I have found.

Comment: @crystallove18 - I responded to your post

Comment: the demo linked in the post is not working anymore.

Comment: Hey sorry about that @beta I forgot about this post and recently that old server was turned off. I will update my post with a fix right away!

Comment: Hello @DrewT, this is nice thanks, any chance you can put this how do the combo-filter on a code pen/jsfiddle site with comments, since seems to be coming frequently. In my case I am trying to figure out how to populate the multiple filters from a backend Server like ASP or Java, so `what do I send the various option-sets into your function so I can reuse your combination filter`? and some comments with code to follow please