# JQuery Isotope Combination Filter - preselection

Tags: filtering, jquery-isotope

I try to implement an Isotope combination filter. One of the three filters should be set to one selection, the other two filters should show all the items according to these filters. Everything works fine with one exception: When clicking the first time, the preselection is "lost" and all the items according to the preselected filter are shown. Only after the preselected filter is clicked, everything works.

As I am a beginner, I have no idea how to this. Any ideas how to solve this?
Thanks a lot!

```
<script>


$('#container').isotope({ filter: '.current' });

$(function(){

var $container = $('#container'), filters = {};

$container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.prod'
});

// filter buttons
$('.filter a').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  // don't proceed if already selected
  if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
    return;
  }

  var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');

  // change selected class
  $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $this.addClass('selected');

  // store filter value in object
  // i.e. filters.color = 'red'
  var group = $optionSet.attr('data-filter-group');
  filters[ group ] = $this.attr('data-filter-value');
  // convert object into array
  var isoFilters = [];
  for ( var prop in filters ) {
    isoFilters.push( filters[ prop ] )
  }
  var selector = isoFilters.join('');
  $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

  return false;
});
```

});

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by pre-selection?

Maybe you're looking for my answere here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886882/combining-elements-for-filtering-with-isotope/20490439#20490439

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The only solution I found was simulating a click on the button for that specific selection after page load.
This is possible with jQuery.
Set an ID for the button in question and call:

```
$("#button_id").click();
```