# Isotope: Combination Filtering with Bootstrap Dropdown

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope

I have Isotope working to filter custom post types for an employee directory in Wordpress. I'm using Bootstrap dropdowns to display three categories set to filter the employees by country, industry and company, but want to be able to combine the results when choosing an option from all three dropdowns.

I'm struggling to combine the selected values into one. Currently, the filters work independently, but when you select from a second category it overwrites the selection made in the first category.

This is the code my PHP is generating to produce the dropdown links for my filters

```
<div id="filters"> <!-- Sorting links -->
        <div data-filter-group="company" class="dropdown directory-filters">
        <button aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownMenu1" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
            Company
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li role="presentation"><a class="selected" data-filter="*" href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">All</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a data-filter=".apac-jwt" href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">APAC JWT</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a data-filter=".thoughtful-media-group" href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Thoughtful Media Group</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a data-filter=".turn" href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Turn</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a data-filter=".venture-consulting" href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Venture Consulting</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div> <!-- end .dropdown -->
        <div data-filter-group="industry" class="dropdown directory-filters">
        <button aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownMenu2" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
            Industry
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li role="presentation"><a class="selected" data-filter="*" href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">All</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a data-filter=".advertising" href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Advertising</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a data-filter=".marketing" href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Marketing</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a data-filter=".media" href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Media</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div> <!-- end .dropdown -->
        <div data-filter-group="country" class="dropdown directory-filters">
        <button aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownMenu3" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
            Country
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3" role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li role="presentation"><a class="selected" data-filter="*" href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">All</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a data-filter=".asia" href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Asia</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a data-filter=".europe" href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Europe</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a data-filter=".north-america" href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">North America</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div> <!-- end .dropdown -->
    </div>
```

Here's the jS I'm running.

```
var $container = $('#isotope-list'); //The ID for the list with all the blog posts
$container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP
    itemSelector : '.item', 
    layoutMode : 'fitRows'
});

//Add the class selected to the item that is clicked, and remove from the others
var $optionSets = $('#filters'),
$optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

$optionLinks.click(function(){
var $this = $(this);
// don't proceed if already selected
if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
  return false;
}
var $optionSet = $this.parents('#filters');
$optionSets.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
$this.addClass('selected');

//When an item is clicked, sort the items.
 var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$container.isotope({ filter: selector });

return false;
});

// store filter for each group
var filters = {};

$demo.on( 'click', '.button', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  // get group key
  var $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.directory-filters');
  var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
  // set filter for group
  filters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
  // combine filters
  var filterValue = '';
  for ( var prop in filters ) {
    filterValue += filters[ prop ];
  }
  // set filter for Isotope
  $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
```

I read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886882/combining-elements-for-filtering-with-isotope/) article on SO, but still can't tell what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Ran across your question, and I'm not sure if this can help, but I found this jsfiddle that someone did that seems to be along the lines of what you're looking to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/SdUQ5/

```
    $(function() {
    var $container = $('#container'),
        $select = $('div#filterGroup select');
    filters = {};

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item'
    });
        $select.change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        var $optionSet = $this;
        var group = $optionSet.attr('data-filter-group');
    filters[group] = $this.find('option:selected').attr('data-filter-value');

        var isoFilters = [];
        for (var prop in filters) {
            isoFilters.push(filters[prop])
        }
        var selector = isoFilters.join('');

        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```